# Cannot access all of PFFacebookUtils Methods

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods, pffacebookutils

I am using cocoapods in my project but when I use:

```
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

I get the following error:

```
no known class method for selector initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions
```

When using intelisence I cannot access this method and my cocoapod for PFFacebook utils is 1.7.4 Is there something im doing wrong and cannot access this method? I see it in the class reference (on parse.com) but I'm unsure why I cant use it within xcode.

Answer (score 1):

In your podfile:

```
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.7'
```

Since these libraries written in Objective-C, you should also create a [bridging-header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) and import the followings:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```